# Symfony 4.3.5 - locale loading nonexistent public

Tags: localization, locale, php-7, symfony-4.3

In Symfony 4.3.5 when using locale in url (e.q. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/example`), framework starts loading nonexisting public route to resources;
`/en/images/like-icon-58x25.png` instead `images/like-icon-58x25.png`.

I got 404 on each of these resources when server tries to access public route with locale prefixed in route, only plain HTML loads:
`[Wed Jan 29 19:17:30 2020] 127.0.0.1:50790 [404]: /en/css/bootstrap.css`
`[Wed Jan 29 19:17:30 2020] 127.0.0.1:50794 [404]: /en/css/style.css`
`[Wed Jan 29 19:17:30 2020] 127.0.0.1:50792 [404]: /en/css/fonts.css`
`[Wed Jan 29 19:17:30 2020] 127.0.0.1:50796 [404]: /en/images/logo-proizd-team-2019-web2.png`
`[Wed Jan 29 19:17:30 2020] 127.0.0.1:50798 [404]: /en/images/project-1-195x164.jpg`
`[Wed Jan 29 19:17:30 2020] 127.0.0.1:50800 [404]: /en/js/core.min.js`
`[Wed Jan 29 19:17:30 2020] 127.0.0.1:50802 [404]: /en/js/script.js`

How to solve this problem. Could not find similar problems and solutions.

Comment: Do you have these asset URLs hardcoded?

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule No, URLs are not hardcoded. They are dynamically created, as I change locale so does the URL to resources.  

If I change locale to ```it```, the path  to resource changes to ```/it/css/bootstrap.css```

Comment: Are you using `ascetics`?

Comment: Can you provide `routes` config and an example of how you use assets inside your templates?

Comment: @JeffSloyer Did you mean ```Assetic```? ```Assetic``` is not recommended to use anymore, instead they recommend using ```Webpack Encore```.

Comment: @ChristosLytras I use annotation routing. One of routes: `@Route("{_locale}/boats", name="boats")`. Example of assets in template: `<div class="iso-1"><span><img src="images/like-icon-58x25.png" alt="" width="58" height="25"/></span><span class="iso-1-big">9.4k</span></div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution.
Since I'm using Twig, assets must be put into `asset()` function.

e.g.

`src="{{ asset('images/like-icon-58x25.png') }}"`